# Queen bee glitch

Tags: terraria

So, I was digging underground when my screen said, "The queen bee has awoken!"
I was away from my house, so I teleported back using a magic mirror. Soon the boss music started at my house, And I ran away. (My house is not at an jungle.) But she followed me! I died on purpose to get her to despawn, but she was still there! What Do I do?

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. This is a perfectly logical question.

Comment: Its a totally unresearched question. *Any* amount of research would answer this handily.

Comment: @Frank Your assumption is false. The OP commented on Ramirez's answer that he did not see this in the Wiki. It's also an oddity for Terraria bosses, making it more obscure. You're more than welcome to your opinion, but from my point of view, there was not a lot of research that could be done.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf what the OP has said is irrelevant. This question *shows* no sign of research. From my point of view, we expect effort. This shows none to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: @Frank If we expect some modicum of effort from our users, then a good deal of questions should be downvoted, yet they are not. I fail to see this as an enforced rule on this site.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Its literally a down vote reason. But I digress. I feel this question shows no effort, so I downvoted. How others vote is their choice, as long as they're voting on the post, and not on users or to counteract other votes.

Comment: A vast majority of questions that I see on this site are "easily researched". They are either things you should be able to figure out on your own after playing the game, or after <5 minutes of looking something up on the related wiki. However, I still think many of those questions are useful, because often it's a hangup that a lot of players run into. Plus for this question in particular, I happen to know that the Queen Bee is probably the glitchiest of bosses available in the game, so I can see how someone might be confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Queen Bee spawns when one of her Larvae is destroyed. Larvae can be destroyed by anything that would destroy a pot, so that includes underground traps and stray projectiles. Rarely, world generation itself will not spawn the Larvae correctly, which then auto-breaks immediately upon loading into the world or if you get close enough to its location.

Under normal circumstances, the Queen Bee will not despawn on her own, even if you die to her. One way to force her to despawn would be to save+quit out of your world, then go back in. Since enemies are unloaded when you quit, the Queen Bee should be gone.

Comment: 3 consecutive queens, 3 times I die, Queen is gone (without quitting the world). Just saying...

Answer (score 8):

This is not a glitch. The Queen Bee was intentionally designed this way, and if you look at the Terraria wiki, you'll see this point in the trivia section:

> Unlike other bosses, Queen Bee will not despawn if the player dies.

So the only way to get rid of her is to kill her or wait for her to despawn herself.

Source: [Terraria Wiki](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj6_ZnrqK7UAhVXImMKHf5NCfEQFgg4MAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fterraria.gamepedia.com%2FQueen_Bee&usg=AFQjCNHEguW8nmnrCF3rLyXtb4CE7pcbrA&sig2=QQtJwVnAUDTy3dYZF7EtUw)

Comment: Ohhh. I never saw that on terraria Wiki.

Comment: Understandable, since it seems kind of odd that that only the queen bee doesn't despawn when you die to it.